# tlab Audio conversion

Tags: matlab, audio

I recorded my voice in Matlab. Now i want to convert that audio in to strings i-e; written sentences in Matlab. Is there a way to convert audio in to text.

Comment: This is a VERY tough problem - even state-of-the-art algorithms are not able to do that. SO is not the place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure MATLAB does not have native speech-to-text functionality.

A quick Google search turned up at least one project integrating speech-to-text into MATLAB.

http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/voicebox.html

Some other software that can translate recorded speech into text are Microsoft's [SAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Speech_API) (built into Windows Vista and Windows 7, and available as a download for Windows XP), and [CMU's Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) project.  Nuance Dragon Naturally Speaking is an option, but it is comparatively expensive.  It's not obvious to me how these could be integrated into MATLAB though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve somewhat limit mileage using the Builtin Windows Speech API. It depends on your operating system etc. and you need to follow similar principles from the API documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(v=vs.85).aspx

Using MATLAB's activeX server (
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html)

You need the first declare a speech recogniser engine

```
RC = actxserver('SAPI.SpSharedRecoContext'); %connect to speech engine
```

And then setup various call back functions for each state of the recogniser:

```
RC.registerevent({'Recognition' @CallbackFunction; 'Hypothesis' @CallbackFunction; 'FalseRecognition' @CallbackFunction})
```

The contents of the callback function should be along these lines:

```
function word = CallbackFunction(varargin)
    global word
    result = varargin{length(varargin)-2};
    word = result.Phraseinfo.GetText;
end
```

Then finally switch the recogniser on:

```
RC.Recognizer.State = 'SRSActive';
```

You would need to reference the documentation for which callback functions are called and when.

You will need to also setup a grammar dictionary to get meaningful results. As the engine will be attempting to recognise any word otherwise.